# Threads in Haiku

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, python-multithreading, haiku

I am running the Haiku desktop in a virtual machine, and have written a threaded python program. The program will create threads on each execution. It works fine the first few times, but if I keep running it, even though the threads are done, they don't seem to exit. Pressing start again will say something like Thread-93, even though it should be Thread-1. Python doesn't have a stop() function or anything. On other operating systems it doesn't seem to be an issue. How do I get the thread to disappear and free those resources in Haiku?

Comment: Post your question on the Haiku development mailing list, it gives you a higher chance for an answer.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Haiku's python port in the Nightly images is much improved.